# load workbook with openpyxl ValueError Duplicate position 0.0

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to open a xlsx file in Python with openpyxl but I've this error :
`raise ValueError("Duplicate position {0}".format(stop.position))
ValueError: Duplicate position 0.0`
I don't understand what does it mean and I haven't found an issue explained for this error. Here is my code in file gestion_fichiers_excel :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

def loadfile():
    workbook = load_workbook(filename="Feuille_decisions.xlsx")
    return workbook**
def get_decisions(workbook):
    num_entreprise=workbook.active["B4"].value
    prix_prod1=workbook.active["B7"].value
    prix_prod2=workbook.active["C7"].value
    list_decisions=[num_entreprise,prix_prod1,prix_prod2]
    return list_decisions
```

And another file which calls gestion_fichiers_excel :

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk
from gestion_fichiers_excel import *

class PageDecisions(tk.Frame):
    def init(self, master):
        self.workbook=loadfile()
        self.list_decisions=get_decisions(self.workbook)
```

Thanks for your help. As you can see, I'm a beginner...

Comment: You likely have a syntax error here `return workbook**`. The two stars mean nothing, maybe something introduced while you copied your code here.
As for your actual problem, can you open your file in Excel without any issue?

Comment: Thanks it's just a mistake that i've done when i've pasted my code but it was not in my code. And yes there's no error when I open my file in Excel and I've tried several number format without success...

Comment: Don't forget to edit it then ;)
From what I see, the exception comes from this [part of the code](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/15df72eae2f93bedc0c0c0cc8753b9107cc82d41/openpyxl/styles/fills.py#lines-154:157). I'm not really aware of how things internally work in `openpyxl` but this seems to be related to `GradientFill`. Sounds like you have a bizarre gradient defined in your Excel file (maybe from a cell style or a graph?).

Comment: Thank you. My file was very simple with no graph and no particular style so I thought that there was another issue. But you were right i think because I just used a new file with few values and now it works !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out this error was introduced in pandas version 1.2.0. Previous versions will load the file successfully.