# It shows ValueError: Duplicate Position 0.0 when loading an Excel file (.xlsm)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I want to loading an Excel file (.xlsm) which contains Excel Macro in header cell. 
It shows like this: 
[A1 cell contains both text and Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9qiw.png)

(Sorry for providing just few information due to business confidential) 
Actually I don't know whether the special-formatted cell as a header lead to this issue:

> ValueError: Duplicate Position 0.0

or because the cell has password to protect so that I can't read?
I also try some ways to fix it but still fail to read the file as below.

I use both pandas and openpyxl to read the xlsm file, show part of it below:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filePath, sheet_name = 'sheet0', header = 0, index_col = None)
or
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath, data_only = True)
sh = wb['sheet0']
```

I just use very common syntax however either I use pandas or openpyxl it shows the same error.
And I also find similiar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365340/load-workbook-with-openpyxl-valueerror-duplicate-position-0-0). It didn't give me an effective solution. 
Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Version of openpyxl is 3.0.10 and pandas is 1.5.1 if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the issue today. To say simply, I just need the text 'LVL' and drop the button function. And I tried to read the file but showed the issue. I think that it's because the cell contains both text and button leading to this situation. 
And the solution shows as below:

```
import pylightxl
wb = pylightxl.readxl(fn = filePath, ws = 'sheet_name')
data = []
for row in wb.ws('sheet_name').rows:
    row_data = []
    for cell in row:
        if isinstance(cell, str):
            #Add to row_data if cell contains text.
            row_data.append(cell)
        elif isinstance(cell, int):
            row_data.append(cell)
        elif isinstance(cell, float):
            row_data.append(cell)
    data.append(row_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
KeyCol_df = df[['KeyCol_A', 'KeyCol_B', 'KeyCol_C', 'KeyCol_D']]
```

The main idea is that I just read the information what I need and append to a list (finally to a dataframe). 
And I check this [site](https://www.python-excel.org/) to determine use `pylightxl` module to read xlsm file. 
Maybe I didn't describe my question clear, I apologize for this.
Thanks anyone who had ever checked this question!